# Limiting the amount of numbers in a user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a 4 digit password guesser in python 3. I want to make sure that you can only put in 4 digit passwords and not 5 or 6 digit passwords. Here is the code I have so far.

```
print('your password will not be used or saved for later use you do   not have to put in your real password')
real_password = int(input("please enter your four digit phone password here:"))
computer_guess = 0000
guess_counter = 0
yes = 'yes'
no = 'no'
print ("guessing your password...")
while computer_guess < real_password:
    computer_guess = computer_guess + 1
    guess_counter = guess_counter + 1
    print("guess number", guess_counter)
print ("your password is", computer_guess)
```

Comment: `if real_password > 9999:`? What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Before you cast the input to an int, cast it to a str instead, then you can call the len() builtin method to check the length of the entered string. Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) for details on this method. If it is greater than 4, then you should recall your input call. Something like the following should work:

```
>>> real_password = input("please enter your four digit phone password here: ")
please enter your four digit phone password here: 1234
>>> while len(str(real_password)) != 4:
...     real_password = input("please enter your four digit phone  password here: ")
```

In this condition the loop would not be ran, however if the entered string was not equal to 4, the loop would run until that condition was satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

```
print('your password will not be used or saved for later use you do   not have to put in your real password')

def get_password():
    real_password = int(input("please enter your four digit phone password here:"))
    if len(str(real_password)) != 4: # condition is not met if your variable
        get_password()               # is not 4, easily changed if you  
    else:                            # want
        return real_password

#define a method and ask it to call itself until a condition is met 
#

real_password = get_password() # here the method is called and the return
computer_guess = 0             # value is saved as 'real_password'
guess_counter = 0
yes = 'yes'                    # these are not used in your code
no = 'no'                      # but I'm am sure you knew that
print ("guessing your password...")
while computer_guess != real_password: # your loop should break when the 
    computer_guess += 1                # is found, not some other implied
    guess_counter += 1                 # the '+=' operator is handy  
    print("guess number", guess_counter) 
print ("your password is", str(computer_guess)) # explicitly define the int 
                                                # as a string
```

I hope that helped...